# PIXI: Change only non transparent pixels of sprite to one solid color

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Here is a solution that just replaces the entire texture with a solid color:

```
sprite.texture = PIXI.Texture.WHITE
```

Obviously this wont work with transparent sprites. Any transparency ends up solid as well. (Resulting in a solid rectangle)

How could I change the color of only non transparent pixels of the sprite?

(tint wont work either since all sprites would have to be white)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't do it with Pixi. According to one of Pixi maintainers [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/32811-replacing-sprite-with-one-solid-color/), you can use dark tint from pixi-heaven package (https://github.com/gameofbombs/pixi-heaven). This exact example is listed in its readme:

> Make whole sprite of one color:
>
> ```js
> sprite.tint = 0xffaacc;
> sprite.color.dark[0] = sprite.color.light[0];
> sprite.color.dark[1] = sprite.color.light[1];
> sprite.color.dark[2] = sprite.color.light[2];
> //dont forget to invalidate, after you changed dark DIRECTLY
> sprite.color.invalidate();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a [custom filter](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters-advanced/custom.js) to the sprite. "Filter" is [PixiJS's term for a shader](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/15731-confused-about-shaders-vs-filters/).

1. Start with this [custom filter example](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters-advanced/custom.js).
2. Modify the file shader.frag with a shader that returns the desired color or transparent, depending on the current pixel.
3. *Optional*: The above will continuously calculate the solid sprite from the original sprite. If performance is a problem, I think there is a way to save the results and set that as the sprite's texture.

The fragment shader should be pretty simple. Here are two good fragment shader tutorials:

- [WebGL Fundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) (Specifically, this part: [WebGL Image Processing](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html))
- [The Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in pure PIXI with `ColorMatrixFilter`:

```
let filter = new PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();
filter.matrix = [
    10, 10, 10, 10,
    10, 10, 10, 10,
    10, 10, 10, 10,
    -1, -1, -1, 1
];
sprite.filters = [filter];
```

AFAIK `tint` and `alpha` might stop working, but you can add additional filters after this one (e.g. `AlphaFilter`) to achieve a similar effect.